# Adding an element into a HashMap in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap which contains a HashMap as value. I would like to add a key-pair value into the HashMap considered as value. I wrote something like this

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> record= new HashMap<>();
record.put("John",....)// I am not sure what to put here
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

```
//get innerMap using key for record map
innerMap = record.get("John");
if(innerMap == null){ // do not create new innerMap everyTime, only when it is null
   innerMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
innerMap.put("Key", 6); // put using key for the second/inner map
record.put("John", innerMap)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> record= new HashMap<>();
HashMap hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("string", 1);
record.put("John", hm);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to get an instance of HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", 1);
```

then

```
recore.put("John", map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this -

```
 HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> record= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> subRecord = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    subRecord.put("Maths", 90);
    subRecord.put("English", 85);

    record.put("John",subRecord);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, That value has to be stored like this :

```
HashMap<String,Integer> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("Your string",56);
```

Then add this value Hashmap into your record hashmap like this:

```
record.put("John",value);
```

Comment: "Your integer" wont work for Integer. Check formatting.

Comment: Yeah True, But I think that's okay for explaining purpose :P

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many answers if you need information on how to fetch the values from the inner Hashmap Please refer this.

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> record= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    
    innerMap.put("InnerKey1", 1);
    innerMap.put("InnerKey2", 2);
```

Storing the value to outer Hashmap

```
   record.put("OuterKey", innerMap);
```

This is how you retrieve the values

```
  Map<String, Integer> map = record.get("OuterKey");
  Integer myValue1 = map.get("InnerKey1");
  Integer myValue2 = map.get("InnerKey2");
```